# python fabric sudo not respecting env.password

Tags: python, fabric

My remote host is Ubuntu. My intent is to run few sudo commands(example: ip route add <>) as a non-root user.
Here is my code snippet:

```
def add_route_in_extrtr(rtrip,route,nexthop,action='add',ostype='ubuntu',user='test',pwd='test123'):
    """
    Adding Routes in ExtRtr(Ubuntu)
    """
    env.host_string = rtrip
    env.user = user
    env.password = pwd
    env.sudo_user = user
    if action == 'add':
            sudo("echo hello")
            sudo("ip route add %s via %s" %(route,nexthop),pty=False)
    if action == 'update':
            sudo("ip route del %s" %(route))
            sudo("ip route add %s via %s" %(route,nexthop),pty=False)
```

Now when the above func is called, then I consistently see the below failure:

```
[172.28.184.38] sudo: echo hello
2016-02-18 09:25:45,221 [INFO] paramiko.transport - Connected (version 2.0, client OpenSSH_6.6.1p1)
2016-02-18 09:25:45,343 [INFO] paramiko.transport - Authentication (publickey) failed.
2016-02-18 09:25:45,373 [INFO] paramiko.transport - Authentication (password) successful!
[172.28.184.38] out: hello
[172.28.184.38] out:

[172.28.184.38] sudo: ip route add 55.55.55.0/24 via 1.102.1.254
[172.28.184.38] out: RTNETLINK answers: Operation not permitted
[172.28.184.38] out:


Fatal error: sudo() received nonzero return code 2 while executing!

Requested: ip route add 55.55.55.0/24 via 1.102.1.254
Executed: sudo -S -p 'sudo password:'  -u "test"  /bin/bash -l -c "ip route add 55.55.55.0/24 via 1.102.1.254"

Aborting.
```

On the Ubuntu server I ran the cmd as is as executed by fabric sudo and it throws the above error.

```
test@ext-rtr:~$ sudo -S -p 'sudo password:'  -u "test"  /bin/bash -l -c "ip route add 55.55.55.0/24 via 1.102.1.254"
RTNETLINK answers: Operation not permitted
```

Also the above route does NOT exist in the linux route table. I checked before calling this func

As per the 'sudo' source-code and the documentation, I could not find what I could be missing. I did try few helps by digging in our stackoverflow archives, but could not pass this failure. Any help or if you can point out what am I missing/doing wrong, is much appreciated

Comment: btw, 'sudo -S' option is intended for accepting password via stdin. So although the env.password is set it is not getting accepted as a stdin. not sure why

Comment: Is user `test` allowed to run sudo? You can have a look at `/etc/sudoers`, if for example group `sudo` is allowed, just add user `test` to the `sudo` group: `sudo adduser test sudo`.

Comment: Yes, the group sudo is allowed, even the user 'test' is the member of the group sudo. From my /etc/sudoers file:  # Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL  .. Furthermore: test@ext-rtr:~$ sudo -l -U test
Matching Defaults entries for test on ext-rtr:
    env_reset, mail_badpass, secure_path=/usr/local/sbin\:/usr/local/bin\:/usr/sbin\:/usr/bin\:/sbin\:/bin

User test may run the following commands on ext-rtr:
    (ALL : ALL) ALL
test@ext-rtr:~$
test@ext-rtr:~$sudo adduser test sudo
The user `test' is already a member of `sudo'